#  Limit  inside an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

Well, I mean, imagine that you have a function: 
$$f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to n}{\dfrac{nx}{x^n}}$$
Would it be possible to write an integral of that? Something like this:
$$\int{\biggl(\lim_{x\to n}\dfrac{nx}{x^n}\biggl)}dx$$

Comment: Limit will return you a constant , and integrating a constant will give you a linear equation.

Comment: Your first bit doesn't make sense as a function of $x$ since $x$ is a dummy variable. As a function of $n$, however, it is fine.

Comment: In general, having a limit inside your integral is no big deal. What you have to be careful about, is having a *limit of integrals*

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x\to n}{\dfrac{nx}{x^n}}$ is a function of $n$.  $x$ is a bound variable in the expression.

Comment: i think that you mean $n\to +\infty$ because for the case $x\to n$ the expresion of $\lim_{x\to n}\dfrac{nx}{x^n}$ will not depend on $x$ will just depend on $n$ is not interesting

Comment: we will calculate the integral of a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can do it but if $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}f_{n}(x)=f(x)\in L^1$

$$\int \lim_{n\to +\infty}f_{n}(x)dx=\int f(x)dx$$

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do it,

$$\displaystyle\int{\biggl(\lim\limits_{x\to n}\dfrac{nx}{x^n}\biggl)}dx= \displaystyle\int L.dx = Lx +c $$

$L= n^{2-n}$

Comment: the limit is not equal to $n$

Comment: sorry , a silly mistake!

Comment: we have $\displaystyle\int L.dx=\displaystyle\int n^{2-n}.dx=n^{2-n}\displaystyle\int dx= n^{2-n}.c$, wher $c$ is a constant.

Comment: @AbdelmajidKhadari: You're missing an $x$ after integrating.

Comment: i miss an $x$, where !? i think we have $\int dx=c$.

Comment: No, $\int \ \mathrm{d}x = x + C$.

Comment: @SauravTomar What's $L$ in this equation? $L=n^{2-n}$

Comment: @Garmen1778 yes L(limit) is $n^{2-n}$